# Downloading Files - Location

Tags: android, xml, download

This is a real newbie question.
I am going to be creating an app that downloads an XML file, which contains links to mp3 files.
Where should I download these files too?

I mean can I bundle the XML file under `/res` and then download the latest XML file over the top of it? Currently I have some mp3 files in `/res/raw.`
Would I be able to do the same?

Comment: what has mp3 got to with xml? You have links for mp3 songs in xml? Download the data parse the xml get the links then download the mp3 to sdcard or internal memory depending on your requirement

Comment: Do you really have to download a file to parse data? You can make HTTP requests to get data & then parse it. 

If you really have to, then save it in your sd card & read the xml data from sd card directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should save your `XML` file in your own directory in SD Card and just read that file content using `XmlPullParser` in your application.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/your_dir/your_xml.xml");
```

- [How to create Folder/Directory in SD card ?](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/12/14/picture-selection-from-camera-gallery/)
- [How to read XML data from SD Card ?](http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/parsing-xml-from-the-sdcard-using-xmlpullparser/)

I hope this is enough as per your requirement.

Comment: In eclipse where would these files be? Like what folder is meant to simulate the sd card?

Comment: for testing purpose Go to DDMS > Select your emulator > mnt > sdcard > ... here you can show all your sd card data.